# How to click on one link among several to which all of them having same id

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to click on one link among several to which all of them having same id.
And it has only one means through which we can get it,that is id.
And through xpath ,we can't do  because every time I open the tab,location of that link changes,so xpath changes too.
There are lots of links having same id,it differs through text written above it.so to refer that link,I also mention it through that text,but still not able to do.

In other words,there are links(with images) placed one by one,on execution,I want 3 link to execute but it executes the first one due to having same id's.so what should I do to click the third link not the first one.

```
<span class="online-signal"></span> 
<figure> 
    <img id="UserImagePreview" src='/Content/PatientPhotos/default.jpg' alt="" /> 
</figure> 
<figcaption class="doc-des-cap" title="Y">Z </figcaption> 
<figcaption>Rating: 4</figcaption> 
<span class="select-btn"> 
    <a id="linkAppointment" docid="727" docname="x" href="javascript:void(0)">Select</a> 
</span>

<span class="offline-signal"></span> 
<figure> 
    <img id="UserImagePreview" src='/Content/PatientPhotos/default.jpg' alt="" /> 
</figure> 
<figcaption class="doc-des-cap" title="C">B</figcaption> 
<figcaption>Rating: 0</figcaption> 
<span class="select-btn"> 
    <a id="linkAppointment" docid="49" docname="A" href="javascript:void(0)">Select</a> 
</span>
```

Comment: pls post the link or html source

Comment: Since you are able to identify the link by looking @ it. it means it should have something different compare to others. We can help if you will put the HTML source here.

Comment: <span class="online-signal"></span>
                    <figure>
                        <img  id="UserImagePreview" src='/Content/PatientPhotos/default.jpg' alt=""  />
                    </figure>
                    
                    <figcaption class="doc-des-cap" title="Y">Z </figcaption>
                    <figcaption>Rating: 4</figcaption> 
                    
                    <span class="select-btn">
                        <a id="linkAppointment" docid="727" docname="x" href="javascript:void(0)">Select</a>
                    </span>

Comment: <span class="offline-signal"></span>
                    <figure>
                        <img  id="UserImagePreview" src='/Content/PatientPhotos/default.jpg' alt=""  />
                    </figure>
                    
                    <figcaption class="doc-des-cap" title="C">B</figcaption>
                    <figcaption>Rating: 0</figcaption> 
                    
                    <span class="select-btn">
                        <a id="linkAppointment" docid="49" docname="A" href="javascript:void(0)">Select</a>
                    </span>

Comment: do not ever paste code as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below xpath

```
//figcaption[contains(@title, 'Y')]/preceding-sibling::figure/img[@id='UserImagePreview']
```

Replace the title with the `<figcaption>` title attribute of the respective img you want to locate

Hope this helps you...if it is still not working kindly get back

Comment: I have shared html source.Please have a look and this similar lines of code having same id's exist above 20. So how to click at suppose on 10th link among 20 links.

Comment: I have edited by above response here we are clicking the img based on figcaption title attribute...pls chk if it is working

Comment: I checked with the xpath //figcaption[contains(@title, 'Y')]/preceding-sibling::figure/img[@id='UserImagePreview'] it is working.Kindly check and get back

Comment: Shortcut to check if xpath is working go to the browser console paste the code and press enter $x("//figcaption[contains(@title, 'Y')]/preceding-sibling::figure/img[@id='UserImagePreview']") it will return the html source of the element